# How to keep tooltip visible when its parent container has a scrollbar?

Tags: css

i have a arrow attached to a div. When this div content exceeds its max-height then a scrollbar is added to it. in doing so this arrow attached on top of div becomes invisible.

How can i make sure that the arrow is visible even when scrollbar is added.

Below is the code,

```css
.first_div {
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
  background-color: yellow;
  align-items: center;
}

.drawer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  top: 55px;
  right: 22px;
  min-height: 40%;
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.drawer header {
  min-height: 38px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.drawer:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 9%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 9px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="first_div">
    <div class="drawer">
      <header>title</header>
      <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried your code in Firefox, I don't see an arrow. Same in Chrome. Is there something wrong with the code, or am I missing something? I do see that the dots are missing in front of `first_div` and `drawer`, but even then: no arrow. Please correct your code.

Comment: created a code snippet based on the code you have provided. i cannot see any arrow

Comment: @XenioGracias I approved your edit, but the problem stays the same, of course.

Comment: hm sorry i don know why its not seen here..but could you guys tell me how to add a uparrow above drawer div. thanks

Answer (score -1):

you need to add `:after` to `header` and scrollbar to `ul`:

I have made some changes in your css code:

Here is the updated fiddle:

```css
.first_div {
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
  background-color: yellow;
  align-items: center;
}

.drawer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  top: 55px;
  right: 22px;
  min-height: 40%;
  max-height: 80%;
}

.drawer ul {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.drawer header {
  min-height: 38px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

header:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 9%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 9px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="first_div">
    <div class="drawer">
      <header>title</header>
      <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Wait what? How is this an answer? Updating his fiddle is never going to help people searching for the same problem.

Comment: @Persijn without modifying how can you answer the question? if there is mistake in my answer please tell me what's wrong with my answer and thanks for down voting  without explanation.

Comment: Modifing the question should only be used to make the question more clear. Or easier to understand. 
The *answer* should be posted as you already have done it. You need to explain what you did. Without the explination the answer is not very good.